# Set a value or call a function on return

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a class with a function like this:

```
class Util {
    public bool flagCompleted = false
    public int calc(int x, int y){
        if(x < 0 || y < 0){
            return -1; //set flagCompleted = true
        }
        if(x == 0 || y == 0){
            return 0; //set flagCompleted = true
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

and whenever I return something `flagCompleted` shold be set to true. This flag should also be set when an Excenption is thrown. The problem is, my "real" function is way larger so I can't just set this value before every return.

EDIT: In addition, the calculations take a certain amount of time, so I want to "wait" for the function to finish and my program to output something like "Waiting...". (This is already done with `new Thread(() => {util.calc(...)}`, I just need to know when it finishes)

Comment: You can't return something from a void function. "and whenever I return something flagCompleted shold be set to true. This flag should also be set when an Excenption is thrown." So basically always? Just set it at the beginning of the function?

Comment: oops, my bad with the "void"
The problem is, that the calculation in my "real" function is way more time consuming, so I wait until the flag is true

Comment: What do you mean you "wait" -- are you using this to signal another thread?

Comment: edited  just now.

Comment: No no no, do not do this to signal another thread that the computation is done. If you need to signal another thread, **signal the thread with a thread signal**. Or use a task.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a promise/future.

Comment: And next time, **start with the real problem**.  What you're doing is called an "XY problem" -- you have some completely wrong idea about how to solve your problem, and you ask a question about how to implement that wrong idea, when you should be asking a question about the real problem you have: how to signal another thread that work is complete.

Comment: **Is the work that you are waiting for CPU bound or IO bound**?  If it is IO bound then do not make another thread! Do asynchronous IO on the UI thread. If it is CPU bound then use the TPL to assign a thread to an idle CPU, and asynchronously wait that task.  Either way you should be using a properly designed and implemented mechanism appropriate to the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> whenever I return something flagCompleted should be set to true. This flag should also be set when an exception is thrown. The problem is, my "real" function is way larger so I can't just set this value before every return.

Sure, that's straightforward: just put your big function in a try-finally:

```
class Util {
    public bool Completed { get; private set; }
    public int Calculate(int x, int y) 
    {
        try 
        {
            blah blah blah
        }
        finally
        {
            this.Completed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

On a return, the `finally` block will run after the return but before the caller is resumed. Things are a little more complicated on a throw; **exception filters in the caller get to run before the finally block**, so be careful if you have state that must be observed by an exception filter and set in a finally. That is possible, but maybe ask another question if that's your scenario.

UPDATE: I have just learned that this mechanism is being used to signal another thread that the computation is complete. **This is the wrong mechanism to use for that**.  If you need to block another thread on this work, use a monitor and signal the other thread. If the other thread is working asynchronously to this one, use a task.

Moreover: if the work being done is CPU bound then use the TPL to schedule a worker thread to an idle CPU, and then await the resulting task. If the work is IO bound then do not create a separate thread. Make the whole method asynchronous by using async IO, keep the whole thing on the UI thread, and await the resulting task.  Either way, **it is smarter to use a task as your signal mechanism**.

When you await the task, if the task completes normally then you'll get the result and your workflow will resume, and if the task completes with an exception, the await will throw and your normal exception handlers can handle it.

Comment: Did't thought about Tasks. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Rurido: There is a more general lesson here. When dealing with multithreaded programs **use the highest level tool designed by experts that solves your problem**.  Your solution was to ignore every tool created by threading experts to solve this problem and build your own amateur solution **out of a single bit**. Modern versions of C# have been carefully designed to make asynchronous workflows easier to write, understand and debug; **use those tools**. They're there to help you!